# Finding means of the absolute values of second differences between elements

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a row vector like so: `[1 5 6 -4 3]`. I want to find means of absolute values of second difference between elements. The second differences in this example are `(6-1)=5 ,-4-5=-9 & 3-6=-3`, and the average absolute mean is `(5+9+3)/3=17/3`.

Is there some way of using MATLAB's efficient matrix/array manipulation to do this nicely?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to use `diff` to compute the second difference, but the results I get are different (`diff(v,2) = [-3, -11, 17]`).

Comment: @VictorHugo: The N-th order difference (`diff(x,N)`) means calling `diff` recursively `N` times. So `diff(X,2)` equals `diff(diff(X))`. For *this* operation however, use @Cyrgo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the second difference you can do the following (v is your vector):

```
v(3:end)-v(1:end-2)
```

and from there to calculating the **mean** of the **abs** olute value, its really a simple step.