# Indexing must appear last in an index expression

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have a vector `CD1` (120-by-1) and I separate `CD1` into 6 parts. For example, the first part is extracted from row 1 to row 20 in `CD1`, and second part is extracted from row 21 to row 40 in CD1, etc. For each part, I need to compute the means of the absolute values of [second differences of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022814/finding-means-of-the-absolute-values-of-second-differences-between-elements).

```
for PartNo = 1:6   

    % extract data                
    Y(PartNo) = CD1(1 + 20*(PartNo-1):20*(PartNo),:); 

    % find the second difference  
    Z(PartNo) = Y(PartNo)(3:end) - Y(PartNo)(1:end-2);  

    % mean of absolute value
    MEAN_ABS_2ND_DIFF_RESULT(PartNo) = mean(abs(Z));    

end
```

However, the commands above produce the error:

```
()-indexing must appear last in an index expression for Line:2
```

Any ideas to change the code to have it do what I want?

Comment: Isn't `Y(PartNo)` a scalar? And the rhs a vector?

Comment: So what is meaning of writing something like that: `Y(1) = [1 2 3]` ? And later `Y(1)(3:end)` - scalar indexing?

Comment: Wait...I fear I've misunderstood your question. Forget my answer, go with @dustincarr's solution in stead :)

Comment: Just a general remark: whitespace is FREE! There's no paper to save in a computer editor, and denser code doesn't make it any faster, so...open it up a bit, it's better on the eyes :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, you actually answered the specific question much better than I did, since the questions was specifically about the error message.

Comment: @dustincarr: Ah, but it wasn't complete to the extent that the error message also occurs when doing `a(2)(3)`, with a an ordinary matrix. But I'll un-delete my question, see what the OP thinks.

Comment: Intersting to know that Octave support multiple indexing. `x = 1:3` then `x(1:2)(2)` is supported

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is often encountered when `Y` is a cell-array. For cell arrays,

```
Y{1}(1:3)
```

is legal. Curly braces (`{}`) mean *data extraction*, so this means you are *extracting* the array stored in location 1 in the cell array, and then referencing the elements 1 through 3 of that array.

The notation

```
Y(1)(1:3)
```

is different in that it does not extract data, but it *references* the cell's location 1. This means the first part (`Y(1)`) returns a *cell*-array which, in your case, contains a single array. So you won't have direct access to the regular array as before.

It is an infamous limitation in Matlab that you cannot do indirect or double-referencing, which is in effect what you are doing here.

Hence the error.

Now, to resolve: I suspect replacing a few normal braces with curly ones will do the trick:

```
Y{PartNo} = CD1(1+20*(PartNo-1):20*PartNo,:);   % extract data
Z{PartNo} = Y{PartNo}(3:end)-Y{PartNo}(1:end-2);  % find the second difference
MEAN_ABS_2ND_DIFF_RESULT{PartNo} = mean(abs(Z{PartNo}));  % mean of absolute value
```

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest a different approach

```
Y = reshape(CD1, 20, 6);
Z = diff(y(1:2:end,:));
MEAN_ABS_2ND_DIFF_RESULT = mean(abs(Z));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a valid statement in matlab:

```
Y(PartNo)(3:end)
```

You should either make `Y` two-dimensional and use this indexing

```
Y(PartNo, 3:end)
```

or extract vector parts and use them directly, if you use a loop like you have shown

```
for PartNo = 1:6   

    % extract data                
    Y = CD1(1 + 20*(PartNo-1):20*(PartNo),:); 

    % find the second difference  
    Z = Y(3:end) - Y(1:end-2);  

    % mean of absolute value
    MEAN_ABS_2ND_DIFF_RESULT(PartNo) = mean(abs(Z));    
end
```

Also, since `CD1` is a vector, you do not need to index the second dimension. Drop the `:`

```
Y = CD1(1 + 20*(PartNo-1):20*(PartNo));
```

Finally, you do not need a loop. You can `reshape` the `CD1` vector to a two-dimensional array `Y` of size `20x6`, in which the columns are your parts, and work directly on the resulting matrix:

```
Y = reshape(CD1, 20, 6);
Z = Y(3:end,:)-Y(1:end-1,:);
MEAN_ABS_2ND_DIFF_RESULT = mean(abs(Z));
```